# Firestore reads - inconsistency between App Engine Quota and Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I started using Firestore recently (Free plan) in my iOS app, the app is in Production now, and I see huge discrepancy in the number of Reads. App Engine Quota shows 1M reads of 0.05M (free quota) (Cloud Firestore Read Operations), while Firebase Console (Database tab) shows just a one hundred reads for today - 10,000 times difference!

The app can still read the data from the servers (it's not from cache as I tried to delete the app and reinstall), so the Firestore functionality is not limited by exceeding the free quota.

Each app user can read only one document (via listener) with applied security rules, and it reads own document only 3-5 times per session. There are about 50 users so far, so the expected number of reads matches Firebase console.

Is there a known bug in App Engine console? 
Is there a way or free tool to understand the source of all those reads?
Which reporting tool is more reliable in general - Firebase Console or App Engine Console?

I appreciate your help guys!

Comment: Please contact Firebase support if you have concerns about the Firebase console or issues with billing.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you figure out the cause?